# Are method declarations (not definitions) possible in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jshint

Can I declare methods that will be used later in JavaScript similarly to C++ Function prototypes.

Comment: What would you need them for?

Comment: How about trying to make jshint accept perfectly fine code (requring some obscure non-standard forward declaration for everything definitely isn't a good practice)? Alternatively, switch to some other lint if it's that broken.

Comment: Actually...it is making jshint not usable..that is big reason...I do need this fixed

Comment: And I do like the correlation to C++

Comment: Since you can declare and redeclare functions in JavaScript, I don't see why you couldn't declare an empty function with given argument signature (or, if you like, have it just throw an exception so it's clear this is the prototype that isn't to be used), and then declare the real function later. What you gain by this isn't clear to me, though. What's the exact problem JSHint has with your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to foward declare a function or method in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107189/is-it-possible-to-foward-declare-a-function-or-method-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as function declarations in Javascript. It doesn't matter what parameters you define in a function, it can be called with any set of values. Example:

```
function test(a, b) {}

test(); // values are not required for all parameters

test(1, 2, 3, 4); // values are not limited to the number of parameters
```

Making the code pass stricter validation is another matter. Then you have to define the functions exactly as you use them. The point of the validation in this case is to keep you from misusing the lack of declarations in the language, as it results in code that is harder to follow.

Comment: @stack.user.1: If you want to validate the code, you have to validate the whole code, or you will naturally get errors for undefined identifiers. Cleaning up the code a bit, you can get the warnings down to a handful that you should address: http://www.jshint.com/reports/71003

Comment: Note: I declared a lot of identifiers at the start of the script to avoid the warnings for those.